# Android thumbnail list

Tags: java, android, mysql, thumbnails, air-native-extension

For my flash app i needed to create a "native extension", which is a native android Java call. This extension builds a string which consist of all image files and their corresponding thumbnails and returns it to Flash.

I'm not a Java programmer and this is my first attempt on writing android code. So after 2 days of digging I came up with this:

```
public String getThumbPaths(Uri uri, ThumbContext ctx) {
    String out = "";
    Cursor cursor = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.queryMiniThumbnails(ctx
            .getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri,
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);


    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {

        String imageId = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID));

        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor images = ctx.getActivity().managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                filePathColumn, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?",
                new String[] { imageId }, null);

        String filePath = "";

        if (images != null && images.moveToFirst()) {
            filePath = images.getString(images.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]));
        }

        out += cursor.getString(1) + ";" + filePath+";";

    }

    return out;
}
```

and the call

```
ThumbContext ctx = (ThumbContext) context;
Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getContentUri("external"); // content://media/external/images/thumbnails
String paths = getThumbPaths(uri, ctx);
```

Everything works well, except for the speed. I don't know if this happens because of Flash-Java-Flash calls or the piece of code above, which i can't check because the compilation happens inside the Flash.

**So my question is: can i speed up this code? Maybe do this without second cursor inside the "for" loop?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several little bits of optimization you can do.

1. `cursor.getColumnIndex(Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID)` will return the same value for every iteration through the cursor. Assign it to a variable outside the loop.
2. `String[] filePathColumn` is assigned the same value on every iteration (and creates a new object on every iteration as well). Move it outside the loop.
3. For the inner `Cursor`, `MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?"` always has the same value. Outside the loop :)
4. Instead of creating `out` as a `String` and appending to it, consider using `java.lang.StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: Thank you David! :) I will definitely add those bits to the code!

Comment: Whoa! David you saved me 1.7 seconds out of total 5. Thanks again!:)